# Using haskell class «Default» from external packages: example request

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Trying to start haskell proxy server [«haxy»](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haxy-1.0.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Proxy-Server.html). With

```
proxyMain :: forall s. HStream s => Settings s -> IO ()
```

and

```
class Default a where
    A class for types with a default value.
    Methods
        def :: a
            The default value for this type.
    Instances
        Default (Cache s), Default (Settings s)
```

Main question is: how do I pass the default settings to `proxyMain`?

And the minor one: what is `:: forall s. HStream s =>` as part of function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`def` is just a predefined `Settings s` object (its definition doesn't care about which type `s` might be needed), not a function. Just pass it like you would any other value (but, as Daniel Wagner points out, with a concrete type, as `def` is a *polymorphic constant*).

```
proxyMain (def :: Settings Foo)
-- Or, using the TypeApplication extension
-- proxyMain @Foo def
```

(where `Foo` is whatever type with an `HStream` instance you are using).

`forall s . HStream s` is a constraint (the `forall s` is optional; it could have been written `proxyMain :: HStream s => Settings s -> IO ()`). In theory, once could create a value of type `Settings Int`. Without the constraint, `proxyMain` would accept that as its argument. Assuming that `Int` is not an instance of `HStream`, the constraint would prevent `proxyMain` from accepting it.

Comment: «Ambiguous type variable ‘s0’ arising from a use of ‘proxyMain’ prevents the constraint ‘(HStream s0)’ from being solved.
Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘s0’ should be. These potential instances exist: instance HStream String -- Defined in ‘Network.TCP’ »

Problem with proxyMain def

Comment: Is it a package problem?

Comment: @GrigoryShepelev It is not a package problem. You just need to choose an instance of `HStream` and tell the compiler about your choice. For example, you could write `proxyMain (def :: Settings String)`. Or the more modern way: turn on `TypeApplications` and write `proxyMain @String def`.

Comment: @DanielWagner thank you. I've been trying to cast like this: `proxyMain (def :: HStream)` unsuccessfully